# Socket file transfer failing

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server which uses the Sender class and a client which uses the Downloader class below. When the client connects to the server, it downloads the database.db and the default.docx perfectly, but when It starts to read the .png files, It throws this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:145)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:308)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:178)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:399)
at data.Downloader.<init>(Downloader.java:18)
at data.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:18)
at main(Client.java:17)
```

Here are my only two methods:

Downloader:

```
public Downloader(Socket socket) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        int filesCount = dis.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
            long size = dis.readLong();
            String fileName = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println(fileName);
            if (fileName.equals("database.db")) {
                List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
                        data.add(line);
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
                parse(data);
            } else if (fileName.equals("default.docx")) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                    bos.write(bis.read());
                }
                bos.close();
                document = bos.toByteArray();
            } else if (fileName.contains(".png")) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                    bos.write(bis.read());
                }
                bos.close();
                Signatures.signatures.add(bos.toByteArray());
            } 
        }
        dis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sender:

```
public Sender(Socket socket) {
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    files.add(new File(Directory.getDataPath("default.docx")));
    files.add(new File(Directory.getDataPath("database.db")));
    for (String signature : Directory.getSignaturePaths()) {
        files.add(new File(signature));
    }
    try {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
        dos.writeInt(files.size());
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getName() + file.length());
            dos.writeLong(file.length());
            dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            int theByte = 0;
            while ((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) { 
                bos.write(theByte);
            }
            bis.close();
        }
        dos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, I checked the getSignaturePaths() method and It returns the correct paths and the .png files are there.

Comment: Are you sure that the `List` of files contains a picture? Is there something printed on stdout after the second file was sent?

Answer (score 0):

You closed the stream and then kept using the socket. Closing either the input stream or the output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.

Comment: When I used dos.close()? Or which one. I looked through the rest of the code and I'm not using socket.close().